# Passing value to LiveData in Android

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I'm new in development and I'm aware that stack isn't for 'full code requests'. But I'm stuck and can't find the solution.

I'm using `Room` database which has two columns - `firstName` and `lastName`. I'm loading the database with passed `firstName` parameter:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM passenger WHERE firstName LIKE :firstName")
List<Passenger>getAllByName (String firstName);
```

It works as supposed.

But.. When I want to update `Passenger`, I need to populate data again, again, and again. There comes `LiveData` and `observer`.

But.. `setValue` in `LiveData` is private and I cannot send any parameters for Query line. There comes MutableLiveData, but how can I implement that?

Comment: Can you explain your query some more? Still not getting it.

Comment: You need to add some further explanation, because I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

@Eduardas Seems like you need to return LiveData instead:

```
LiveData<List<Passenger>> getAllByName (String name);
```

And you can write a transformation in the ViewModel or you can directly observe it from your Activity/Fragment.

In activity/fragment onCreate() or onResume():

```
YourDao.getAllByName(name).observe(this, new LiveData<List<Passenger>>(){
   @Override
   public void onChanged( @Nullable List<Passenger>) {
     // update your adapter if the list isn't null
   }
});
```

Something similar to above. You can add customization as per your use case.

Comment: Can you please add a comment as in why the answer was down voted?